# Clean emails async using Task.Factory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, email, asynchronous

What I'd like to do is have my code take a list of emails and feed each one to a service to be verified as valid asynchronously.

The service I'm using is [Cobisi .NET Email Verify](http://cobisi.com/email-validation/.net-component) that allows you to verify an email as valid to various verification levels by calling their Task-based asynchronous API.

Using this blog post (http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToParallelBasicsDontBlockYourThreadsMakeAsyncIOWorkForYou.aspx) I think my code will asynchronously validate my list of emails and return an array of Task< bool > representing the emails that passed validation, however I'm not sure how to use this array in Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll() to return a collection of clean emails.

**Here is my code so far**

*Async Email Validation Method:*

```
public async Task<bool> ValidateEmailCleanAsync(string email)
    {
        using (var _engine = new VerificationEngine())
        {
            var verification = new Verification(email);
            await _engine.RunAsync(verification, VerificationLevel.CatchAll);
            return verification.State.Result.LastStatus == VerificationStatus.Success;  //returns true if validation is passed or false if not
        }
    }
```

*Task Factory To Validate Emails:*

```
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(
            (from email in cleanEmailList1 select ValidateEmailCleanAsync(email)).ToArray(),
            completedTasks => { /* Create New String Collection For Clean Emails */ });
```

Is there a way to put in some code where my comment block is to either build a new collection of clean emails or add them to a pre-constructed collection?  Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite the fork-join to use await and everything becomes simple again:

```
var tasks =
  (from email in cleanEmailList1 select ValidateEmailCleanAsync(email)).ToArray();

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

ProcessTasks(tasks);
```

`ProcessTasks` can be anything you like.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.  Unfortunately now when the "await _engine.RunAsync(verification, VerificationLevel.CatchAll);" line runs it appears to just process forever without ever returning to the debugger.  Though I assume that is more of a problem with my use of the Colbisi software than trying to run these tasks in parallel.

Comment: Either that our you have called Wait or Result somewhere causing the classic ASP.NET deadlock.

Comment: That may be it, I'll look out for instances where I may have done that in the "ProcessTasks" portion.  Thanks again.